# Why does my app crash when i use start button in main activity to access login activity?

Tags: android

When i click button START on main activity, crashes before it opens the login activity. What do i do to stop the app from crashing?

I have connected the application to firebase and written the code i think is right. Kindly help solve the code wherever i might have mistaken.

I expect when i click button in the main activity to open login activity that requires user email and password and pop up of log in successful. Instead i get a " has stopped" message.

code for the `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.kiki.doctorlocation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtn);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class));
                }
            }
        };


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

code for `MainActivity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/docto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startbtn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="START"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

code for the `login.java`

```
package com.kiki.doctorlocation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtemail, txtpassword;
    private TextView txtsign_up;
    private Button btnlogin;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        txtemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        txtsign_up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsign_up);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        txtsign_up.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
    }

    public void registerUser() {
        String email = txtemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = txtpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            //if email is empty
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            //if password is empty
            Toast.makeText(this,"Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //if user is validated
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging user in...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Log in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Log in Failed, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        if(view == btnlogin ){
            registerUser();
        }
        if(view == txtsign_up){
            //open signup activity
        }
    }
}
```

code for `login.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/doc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".login">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/roundsedttxt"
        android:hint="Enter email"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/roundsedttxt"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtsign_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create a new account"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your error log

Comment: Does your `login` activity inherit (implement) the `View.OnClickListener` interface? It seems it doesn't, therefore your `onCreate` method probably causes a `ClassCastException` when you set it as onClickListener

Comment: kindly show me how. I am just learning Android on my own

Comment: Thank you so so much, the code just worked

Answer (score 0):

your app crashes because your login activity doesnt implement OnClickListener therefor your activity cant be cast into it just implement View.OnClickListener and you will be good to go Like this :

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `login` activity class code. please modify below two lines,

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
txtsign_up.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
```

Like this,

```
btnlogin.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
txtsign_up.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Add this `clickListener` as global variable.

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btnlogin){
            registerUser();
        } else if(view.getId() == R.id.txtsign_up){
            //open signup activity
        }
     }
});
```

**Notes:** Always name your activity with camelCase naming convention like `LoginActivity`, not just `login`.